# Import Error: No module named AppKit

Tags: python, appkit

I use `Mac OS X Lion` and `Python 2.7`. I am new to python. Can anyone tell me how to `import` `AppKit` and `PyObjC` to `Python`. But i get the errors when trying to import `Import Error: No module named AppKit` or '`Import Error: No module named PyObjC`.

Trying `easy_install` does not help either. [image: This is a screenshot when I run <code>easy_install PyObjC</code>]

What can i do to import these 2 modules?

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: @Eric: I am using `Python 2.7`

Comment: You only need to import AppKit in order to use PyObjc, btw.

Comment: @rien333: Yes, that's it but how to import AppKit?

Comment: Well, just enter 'import AppKit' in the Python shell (or in a script) and if it doesn't return an error it is correctly installed.

Comment: @rien333: Well I get an error while doing `import AppKit` i.e `Import Error: No module named AppKit`. That's why I asked the question. :P

Comment: @rien333: When I type and execute `./project-tool.py -k -v --template Cocoa-Python\ Application/CocoaApp.xcodeproj/TemplateInfo.plist Cocoa-Python\ Application ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Project\ Templates/CocoaPython/Cocoa-Python\ Application` as described in the side, I get the error `ImportError: No module named Foundation`. :(

Comment: You do have XCode with the command line tools (I'm not 100% if you need those) installed, right?

Comment: I did as per the link. But I want to use PyObjC in python not in Xcode. There was no error when I as the site asked but python still gives errors when trying to import PyObjC

Comment: I see, but in order to import AppKit and use PyObjc you need to have XCode installed.

Answer (score 32):

If not already installed, install `pip` by running:

```bash
sudo easy_install pip
```

Then run:

```bash
## install for all users
sudo pip install pyobjc
```

or

```bash
## install for current user only
pip install pyobjc --user
```

> <sup>*NOTE: the general recommendation is to *avoid* using the system python, and use instead a user-maintained version, for example installed via `brew install python3`, `macports`, `conda` or whatever you already use for third party dependencies.*</sup>

Comment: this worked.  Took a long time but it solved my issue

Comment: What if I cannot install external modules?

Answer (score 8):

If you're on Mac it could be you're using the incorrect pip version, try sudo **pip3** install -U pyobjc that solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

This a good guide on how to install PyObjc: http://ioanna.me/2009/09/installing-pyobjc-xcode-templates-in-snow-leopard/

When I was trying to install PyObjc I found it quite hard,  but after a while, (and lots of google searches) I got it working.

**Edit**

I've found a more modern guide on how to do this. Download the [templates](https://github.com/gregneagle/Xcode4CocoaPythonTemplates) and put them into your `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/` directory, and everything should work correctly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864650/importerror-no-module-named-pyobjc/12864785#12864785

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PyCharm, you should install `PyObjC` package manually within it because of venv I guess. This was the only working solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case none of them worked. I was using Anaconda in my mac, later I discovered that the main issue with the Anaconda. Then I installed `PyObjC` with it's all supporting libraries inside Anaconda in a specific Environment.

[image]

I run the command line by clicking the Environment play icon and run my script.

[image]

It worked without any issues :)

Answer (score 0):

If you've tried:

`sudo pip install pyobjc`

And it still isn't working then you may have at some point in the past accidentally installed an incorrect AppKit. Run:

`sudo pip uninstall appkit`

And then try

`sudo pip install pyobjc`

again. The issue I faced was that the other appkit was lowercase so wasn't recognised (and was the wrong package) but it was preventing pyobjc from installing the correct version of AppKit.