# ImportError: No module named pyobjc

Tags: python, pyobjc

I am new to Python. I am running Mac OS X 10.8.2, Python 2.7.3, Xcode 4.5.1.
I am not able to `import pyobjc` to python.I used `easy_install pyobjc` or manually downloading it from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyobjc/2.3 and running `python setup.py install`. Here is a screenshot of my `site-packages folder` [image]

How do I solve this?

Here is a screenshot of sys.path.PyOBJc is present in sys.path 
[image]

Comment: Are you literally using `import pyobjc`?  Looking at the samples, on the sourceforge site, it appears that you're supposed to call `import objc` or `import py2app`, or `from PyObjCTools import AppHelper`, etc.  Take a look at the samples.

Comment: `import objc` all say module not present

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a `.pth` file for `pyobjc` in your `site-packages` directory there.

`.pth` files, placed inside a directory already on Python's search path, contain directories to add to that search path.  They're simple text files; you can review the ones already there to get a feel for how they work.

As to *why* you didn't get `.pth` files for `pyobjc`, I'm not sure.  But you could create some to fix the problem up.

Further reading: [Modifying Python’s Search Path](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#inst-search-path)

Comment: I tried seeing the system path. It shows PyOBJC. But still it don't work

Answer (score 1):

The module name for PyObjC is not "pyobjc".

To use the low-level bridge use "import objc"

To access the Cocoa framework use "import Cocoa".

If "import objc" gives an import error you probably have a number of Python interpreters, check if the value of "sys.prefix" is what you expect it to be. Also check if "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Version/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages" is on "sys.path".